# Branch.io Deep link always return empty on Cordova

Tags: cordova-plugins, handler, branch.io, deeplink

I have a problem of getting the data from branch.io deep link.

First, I create a link on Branch.io dashboard and tested it out and seems to be working fine. It even shows the number of clicks, like the image shown here:
[Branch.io Dashboard link status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoERR.png)

After that, I try to add data on the link as shown here:
[Branch.io deeplink data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SpGt.png)

The code that I am using now is based on the docs:

```
handleBranch: function() {
        console.log("HANDLING BRANCH");
        // Branch initialization
        Branch.initSession().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          if (data['+clicked_branch_link']) {
            // read deep link data on click
            console.log('Deep Link Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
          }
        });
      },
```

At first, I got an error saying **DeepLinkHandler undefined**. So, after doing some research, I found out that I need to add additional function called **DeepLinkHandler**. Below here is the function I used to do the handling:

```
function DeepLinkHandler(data) {
    console.log("inside DeepLinkHandler");
    if (data) {
        alert('Data from deep link: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    } else {
        alert('No data found');
    }
}
```

It seems working so far without error, but the data is always empty. I cannot see the key or value which I set on the dashboard. The alert is always resulting in **Data from deep link: {}**

What did I do wrong here? And how it actually should be done? Could not find about this issue on the docs on how to handling the deep link

Answer (score 0):

You can use Branch's React Native SDK to consume link data. This would be the best step forward compared to manually managing the link. In order to read the referral link's data, you can register a subscriber callback function using the **branch.subscribe** method as shown below:

```
branch.subscribe(({ error, params }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error from Branch: ' + error)
    return
  }

  // params will never be null if error is null

  if (params['+non_branch_link']) {
    const nonBranchUrl = params['+non_branch_link']
    // Route non-Branch URL if appropriate.
    return
  }

  if (!params['+clicked_branch_link']) {
    // Indicates initialization success and some other conditions.
    // No link was opened.
    return
  }

  // A Branch link was opened.
  // Route link based on data in params.
})
```

With this approach, you will receive a callback to consume the link data associated with a referral link everytime your app is opened. You can check out our [documentation](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/#read-deep-link) and gold standard [sample apps](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/tree/master/examples) for further reference.

Please feel free to reach out to us at integrations@branch.io in case of any further questions!